# jQuery gets included twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem in my rails app that jQuery is included twice. Once it's referenced normally with a script tag and once minimized inside application.js. I noticed it because the destroy confirmation messages were popping up twice.

So is there a way to turn off the minimized version locally?

My head looks like:

```
<head>
  <title>Wirent</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

My application.js looks like:

```
//...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're including it manually? Either remove the `<script>` tag or remove `//= require jquery` in `application.js`.

Comment: I am not including it manually. Added snippet of my head to my question.

Comment: There's nothing suspicious in the code you've shown. What does the generated html look like?

Comment: Check my answer found out why it did that. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Glad you found your answer! I'll keep that gotcha in mind.

Comment: @Pickels accept your answer so it doesn't come up on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because I pre-compiled my assets. So assets were also being loaded from public/assets.

This answer explained it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7778048/145117