# Rails UJS link_to :remote does AJAX GET and normal <a href> GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, ujs

**EDIT:**

In addition to the helpful comments below, two excellent articles by Steve Schwartz explain everything clearly:

- http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/
- http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/

Rails 3.2.2 / jquery-rails 2.0.1 *(uses jquery 1.7.1)*

I have link which sends an AJAX request to add additional file upload fields to a form.  **Everything page-related works correctly** - the new form field HTML fragment is retrieved from the server and appended to a div inside the form.

However,

The server receives two GET requests. One is the AJAX request ; the other appears to be the "normal" anchor element GET.  I expected the "normal" GET would be stopped by Rails UJS.

Am I supposed to disable the normal link action myself?  Can someone please explain what I have misunderstood, and what I should be doing instead [to prevent the second request]?

I've seen this question: [Rails 3 UJS - controller gets called twice by link_to :remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231885/rails-3-ujs-controller-gets-called-twice-by-link-to-remote).  Accordingly, I tried changing the asset pipeline compilation `config.assets.debug = false`, but it had no effect.  Moreover, this is not a double-AJAX GET request, so I think it's a different issue.

Thanks for any help!

**Server log snippet:**

```
Started GET "/files/new?asset_number=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-23 15:23:27 +0100

Started GET "/files/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-23 15:23:27 +0100
```

**Browser HTML:**

```
<a href="/files/new" data-remote="true" id="add_another_file" position="after" update="files">Add another file</a>
```

**View:**

```
<%= link_to 'Add another file', new_file_path, :remote   => true,
                                               :update   => 'files',
                                               :position => 'after',
                                               :id       => 'add_another_file' %>
```

**Controller's coffeescript:**

```
$( ->
  $('a#add_another_file').click( ->
    url = '/files/new?asset_number=' + $('#files input').length
    $.get(url, ((data) -> $('#files').append(data)), 'html')))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're adding a `click` event to `a#add_another_file` , then you don't need to use `:remote => true` , because you're making the Ajax request manually.

Also, the `click` event should prevent the default action from occurring. This can be accomplished by adding `event.preventDefault();` to the beginning of the *click* event's callback. Note that the callback needs to accept the `event` argument.

Comment: I'm following along in Rails 3 In Action, which provided the code.  I think using `:remote` would be the right way.  If there should not be a manual `$.get()`, then I'm confused about how it works period, I'll investigate.  And thanks for the event tip!

Comment: this answer totally saved me, -> while using backbone events + jquery bind, browsers handled it OK, ie8 though didnt, because of what you explained. Great insight!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the `:remote => true` option, you should remove the custom *click* event that you've added. This is because the `:remote => true` option tells the *jquery_ujs* library to hijack clicks on `a#add_another_file`. Thus, you needn't make your own HTTP request.

Next, to dictate what's done with the response, bind to the various events that will occur on `a#add_another_file`, such as *success* and *error*.

Here's the [full list of Ajax events that you can bind to](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events#Events).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple, your remote `link_to` is sending one request (without params) and you've added a click event on that link to send another one (with params).

You should simplify your `link_to` as:

`<%= link_to 'Add another file', new_file_path, :id => 'add_another_file' %>`

Then in your `click` event you should return false so it doesn't follow the url.

It looks like you're using a lot of unnecessary parentheses in your coffeescript.

```
$ ->
  $('a#add_another_file').click ->
    url = '/files/new?asset_number=' + $('#files input').length
    $.get url, ((data) -> $('#files').append(data)), 'html'
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` should be used instead of `return false;` . See this article for more info: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: As below, I'd like to do this with `:remote`.  Thanks also for the coffeescript feedback, I'll clean up the style.