# twitter bootstrap dropdown in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get a dropdown working, inside navbar using twitter bootstrap, I have:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>     
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </div><!--/.navbar-inner -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->
```

and the javascript in included in the head has follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    ...
```

So jquery is being included before bootstrap.js, what I'm missing ? what I'm doing wrong ?

Edit:
I've cleaned my application.js so now the head looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

And now appears a white triangle pointing up, that wasn't appearing before, but doesn't appear the whole dropdown...

[image]

Comment: Have a slight suspicion that its not working because you are including the bootstrap plugins twice. Once in each individual plugin script and again on the `bootstrap.js` main plugin sheet. So remove either the loose scripts or the main pack script and see if it works.

Comment: I don't know why are being included twice in my application.js I only have this: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231885/rails-3-ujs-controller-gets-called-twice-by-link-to-remote/7778048#7778048) answer.

Comment: Ok, I've tried that and it has made a small progress but still not working completly, I've edited my answer

Comment: The bootstrap JS is now gone. Include only the `bootstrap.js` script pack (it comes with all of the bootstrap plugins included, so no need to include the loose script files...including both has been known to cause issues like this)

Comment: That's what I thought and I did, but didn't work, also tried to include the boostrap.js at the bottom of the view and it didn't work either

Comment: Post a link to your dev site to take a look, don't know what else it might be without looking at your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be some twitter bootstrap modals that I was using in my layouts like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_terms">
```

Instead of that I've changed to:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="modal_terms">
```

And it's all working properly now, I hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your Markup in an isolated environment: http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/9992A/ (looks good)
2. Maybe you should include the Javascript files at the bottom of the page.
3. Did you use Scaffolding (`$ rails g controller ...`)? If yes remember that the rails scaffold generators often add css files that will screw your bootstrap css. Try to remove them.
4. Clear the Cache of your Browser

Comment: 3. I've used the scaffolding but I've removed all the css files generated and it didn't work either

Comment: 4.I've tried, and also tried on chrome and firefox, still not working