# Why is this twitter-bootstrap drop down not working in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-rails

This seems so simple, yet I can't figure it out.  For some reason, clicking on the dropdown menu is not working, yet everything else in twitter bootstrap is.  I'm using ruby on rails.  I've already looked at stackoverflow questions that say to simply wrap the whole ul in a div with class "drop down-menu", but that shouldn't be necessary.  I should be able to do it inside the ul tag.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

```
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%=link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

That is the main code where I believe the problem is.  It might be somewhere below (same as above but with less taken out) but i doubt it:

```
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
      <% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%=link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <%= "Technically signed in.  should be true.  It is: " + signed_in?.to_s %>

      <% else %>
        <%= "Technically not signed in.  should be false.  It is: " + signed_in?.to_s %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Here is the application.js file

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I had this same problem the other day with the navbar's dropdown menu. It worked when I moved "//= require twitter/bootstrap" to be the first one required in Application.js. But then it didn't work in production =(, had to put that line back where it was for it to work in development.

Comment: is your <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown"> wrapped under a <ul> ?

Comment: Also may be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885684/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-in-rails-3

Comment: Still not working. Ghar, I tried that but its not working. Raghu, it is wrapped under a <ul> and that is a different question.

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code?  Maybe start w/ the <ul> preceding the <li id="fat-menu" etc.>

Comment: Helios, just added all the code.  thanks.

Comment: Your HTML seems fine. I would guess it's something related to the dropdown JavaScript not being included properly.

Comment: I added the application.js file above

Comment: I agree, html looks fine... Are you attaching any other behaviors to the <li id="fat-menu">?

Comment: I haven't added any behaviors.

Comment: If you type the following in the javascript console, does it return true? `(typeof $().dropdown == 'function');`

Comment: I have never used the js console before.  I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Are you using chrome?  Go to the settings button, Tools -> Javascript Console...  Then just copy and paste the code in the console area...

Comment: Also, I know Turbolinks has caused some issues with Javascripts in the past... you might try to remove Turbolinks temporarily or see if a gem like the one here solves your problem: [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Comment: It returns: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdown' of null

Comment: Removing Turbolinks does not fix it.

Comment: Hmm, that TypeError indicates that jQuery isn't loading... Can you move your require jQuery to the top of application.js

Comment: Hmm, tried it but it still isn't working.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  The Javascript was not being called properly.  I deleted and recreated the application.js file, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. I disabled turbolinks from application.js.

1. Remove from `application.js`:

   //= require turbolinks
2. Remove turbolinks gem from Gemfile.
3. Precompiled assets:

   bundle exec rake assets:precompile
4. Deployed my app to Heroku and everything worked like expected.

Comment: It's a shame nobody upvoted you until now. Thanks for the answer, turbolinks was causing this issue for me.